# Recursion instead of looping

Tags: arrays, loops, go, recursion

I'm new in Go programming, so how to implement recursion instead of a for loop in this code?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    set(n)
}

func set(n int) {
    a := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&a[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to be recursive. But as I understand your question as changing a for-loop into a recursion, I made it into a tail recursion in a closure, in a functional programing style.

```
func set(n int) {
    a := make([]int, n)
    var setRecursive func(int) // declare a function variable, which take an int as param.
    setRecursive = func(i int) { // set the function in closure, so a and n is available to it.
        if i == 0 { // end point of the recursion, return.
            return
        }
        Scan(&a[n-i]) // Use fmt.Scan out of playground
        setRecursive(i - 1) // tail recursion.
    }
    setRecursive(n) // call the function, start the recursion.
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

If you want the matter simpler, you can remove the closure part and move the line `Scan(&a[n-i])` behind the line `setRecursive(n)`, Like below:

```
func SetRecursive(a []int, n int) {
    if n==0 {
        return
    }

    SetRecursive(a,n-1) // recurse first, so we can scan in the right order.
    Scan(&a[n-1])
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0io190tyviE

Answer (score 0):

My syntax may be a little off, so I commented what each line does. Essentially, you would get one item of the array each time, and attach an array of one smaller in front of it, which you get by getting a value and attaching an array of one smaller in front of that, until that value is 1 and you're just getting a value.

```
func set(n int) []int {    // declare a function that takes an int as a parameter
                           // and returns an int array
    var recRet = []int{}       // need a temporary array to store return value
    a := make([]int, 1)        // make an array of one to get the value this iteration
    if n < 1 {                   //should never be here but prevents looping
       return nil              // escape
    }
    if n > 1 {                  // if we're not in the base case
        recRet = set(n-1)      // recurse on a list one smaller and store it
    }

    fmt.Scan(&a[1])            // get the value for this iteration
    fmt.Println(a)             // print it
    return append(a, recRet...)// send this value plus the values gotten from recursion
                               // back up
}
```

Comment: This code will not work. `return null` is an error since there is no `null` in Go. `fmt.Scan(&a[i])` is a runtime error because `a` is always a slice of `len=1 cap=1`, and `a[i]` will panic due to out of range when i>1.